# MySQL query - Getting people out that arent in another table?

Tags: mysql, sql

i hope i explain this correctly.

What i have is this query..

```
SELECT *  FROM classesbooked 
JOIN name ON NameNo = classesbooked_nameno
Group By classesbooked_nameno
```

This gets me out all the names of people who have booked a class. What i want is the opposite. All the people who are in table 'name' but not in table 'classesbooked'

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a left join and select records where the second table's join column is null.

```
select *
from name n
    left join classesbooked c on n.NameNo = c.classesbooked_nameno
where c.classesbooked_nameno is null
```

Comment: Phew, I was getting worried that noone know about `LEFT JOIN` anymore :)

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways you can accomplish this is with a sub query:

```
SELECT *
FROM name
WHERE NameNo NOT IN (
                       SELECT 
                          classesbooked_nameno
                       FROM classesbooked
                    )
```

Essentially this says to return everything in table `name` that does not have an associated Id in `classesbooked`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
   Select * from name tbl
        where tbl.NameNo 
        not in (select t.classesbooked_nameno 
                 from classesbooked_nameno t)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM name 
  LEFT JOIN classesbooked 
    ON NameNo = classessbooked_nameno 
WHERE classesbooked_nameno IS NULL
```